# Bootstrap padding/margin issue in 3 column layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Given a layout like this:

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clJAH.png)

I have the following HTML/CSS setup. I need to get the surrounding div to line up with the top and bottom of the center image, but it doesn't seem to be working. It also breaks when resizing the screen, and losing the main surrounding div as the background color changes.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="col-lg-12 contact">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="lib-panel">
      <h4>Let's get to work</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum.Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum.Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum.Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum.Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum.</p>
      <div class="btn btn-default">Button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="lib-panel">
      <div class="right-arrow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="lib-panel">
      <h4>Questions?</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum</p>
      <div class="btn btn-default">Button</div>
      <div class="btn btn-default">Button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.right-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/300x250");
  padding: 15px;
  height: 240px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.right-arrow:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #dde1e2;
}

.contact {
  background-color: #19223c;
}

.contact p,
h4 {
  color: $white;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/kh0prtc4/6/

Comment: are you looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kh0prtc4/3/

Comment: you forgot using `class="row"` and should learn using the bootstrap grid correctly.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith - that actually breaks it a bit. I'm just trying to get the padding correct, so that the image touches the top and bottom of the container, like the image I provided in the question shows.

Answer (score 0):

You should use your row and container classes also if you want it to be bigger or smaller at smaller screens you can add the col-sm-4 col-xs-12 classes or something.  If you want your container to not have the top and bottom padding just add

```
.contact .container{
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Your html:

```
<div class="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="lib-panel">
          <h4>Let's get to work</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum.Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum.Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum.Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum.Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum.</p>
          <div class="btn btn-default">Button</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="lib-panel">
          <div class="right-arrow"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="lib-panel">
          <h4>Questions?</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolorset amicum</p>
          <div class="btn btn-default">Button</div>
          <div class="btn btn-default">Button</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/qzvhs3ek/)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution was just a margin issue. I needed to add

```
margin-bottom: -25px;
margin-top: -10px;
```

to the `.right-arrow` class in order to have it match the container.

Comment: You should always add an updated fiddle if possible, you can change the OP fiddle, click on Update and use that link ;)